# Android 3G Connection

Tags: android, android-wifi

When i am using wifi network all is working fine ,,but when i turn off all network(Not Airplance mode) and turn on 3G HotSpot then my application is not even detecting connection.So web service shwoing timeout errors.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService
(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);;
boolean 3GCon=cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected()
```

This returning always false

Comment: I am in urgency please help me

Comment: What do you mean by 'turn off all network'? Do you meant that you only disable the WiFi, or that you turn on 'airplane mode'?

Comment: What is `cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState()` returning?

Comment: @Greath: i turn on wifi, bluetooth except 3G.No i have not turn on airplane mode

Comment: Ok, and which version of the SDK are you using? As @Maggie has answered, have you tried 'isAvailable()' instead?

Comment: i am using 2.2 motorola mile stone,and i have tried isAvailable();      But in case 3G it didnot detect any network.and if i go inside without checking connection ,then time out exception came

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try using isAvailable() instead of isConnected()?

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to give you an exact answer as to why it's not working for you, but as a start I suggest you look through an example such as [this ConnectivityManagerTestActivity](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/tests/ConnectivityManagerTest/src/com/android/connectivitymanagertest/ConnectivityManagerTestActivity.java.shtml) and compare it with your own code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hot spot'? A 3G connection should work, assuming you have a 3G service in your area.

Comment: Thanx for your quick responce..yes,,my local 3G service,If i browse data on explorer then internet connection is working but its not working in android code,,even not detecting